# Resource recommendation for time-dependent DMRG

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, tensor-network

I am looking for any references (journal article/ review /tutorial) to understand the TEBD (Time-evolution by block decimation) algorithm and code it up for a simple 1D model system.  Broadly, I am interested in getting the dynamics of a model system that obeys the entanglement area law using a time-dependent DMRG like method.

Here are a few references that I've found:

- [The density-matrix renormalisation group in the age of matrix product states](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477)
- [Time evolution methods for matrix product states](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05824)
- [Time-dependent density-matrix renormalization-group using adaptive effective Hilbert spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0403313)

While these are some good references, I am looking for a paper to reproduce some results.